# How can I move an EllipsePath using animation in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, slider

I want to make a slider button using WPF. So I have this code to create a circle and to move it when clicked.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Border Background="LightGray" Margin="167,63,224,190" CornerRadius="20,20,20,20" Height="40" Width="80">
        <Path Fill="Red">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry Center="20,20" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20"/>
            </Path.Data>
            <Path.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" ShadowDepth="2" Color="Gray"></DropShadowEffect>
            </Path.Effect>
            <Path.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseDown">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Center" Duration="0:0:0.3" From="20,20" To="60,20"></PointAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Path.Triggers>
        </Path>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

It is okey that it shows up when program started. But it throws an exception when clicked on it. The error is `System.InvalidOperationException`. So how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is something closer to what you are looking to do?

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Border Background="LightGray" Margin="167,63,224,190" CornerRadius="20,20,20,20" Height="40" Width="80">
        <Canvas>
            <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="40" Height="40" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
                <Ellipse.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" ShadowDepth="2" Color="Gray"></DropShadowEffect>
                </Ellipse.Effect>
                <Ellipse.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseDown">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Duration="0:0:0.3" From="0" To="40" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Ellipse.Triggers>
            </Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes that is what I want and it works well.. But why `PointAnimation` and `Center` property of `Ellips doesn't work?. Do you have an idea about that?

Comment: Well, with the xaml like you had it, there was no way for the storyboard animation object to resolve the "Center" property.   You never set the "Storyboard.Target" value, to let the storyboard know of the source object whose property is being animated.